# Query missing fields on record page vs running in execute anonymous

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I needed to create a lightning component displaying some error tracking data with color coding, hover help text, etc.

Anyway, when running my component from a record page, the Error_Text__c does not display in the query results of my system.debug statement.  The field is a Text(200).  When I run the apex method directly from the Execute Anonymous window it works.  I tried running it with sharing, without sharing, etc and it still had the same behavior.  My user is an admin and I have access to the field (I created it).  I also tried making a wrapper for it to see if that would help and it shows the same behavior.  The code as of now:

```
public class  OutboundErrorLogController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<ErrorWrapper> retrieveErrorLines(Id recordId) {
        List<Outbound_Error_log__c> lstLog= [SELECT Id,Name,CorrectType__c,Interface__c,createddate,Error_Text__c
                FROM Outbound_Error_Log__c WHERE claim__c = :recordId];
        List<ErrorWrapper> lstW = new List<ErrorWrapper>();
        for(Outbound_error_log__c o : lstLog){
            system.debug(o);
            
            ErrorWrapper ew = new ErrorWrapper();
            ew.InterfaceNm=o.Interface__c;
            ew.CorrectType=o.CorrectType__c;
            //ew.CorrectiveAction=o.Error_Message__R.CorrectiveAction__c;
            ew.CreatedDate=o.CreatedDate;
            system.debug(o.error_text__c );
            ew.ErrText=o.Error_Text__c ;
            
            
            lstW.add(ew);
            
            system.debug(ew);
        }
        return lstW;
    }
    
    
    public Class ErrorWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public string InterfaceNm {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public string CorrectType {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public string CorrectiveAction {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public datetime CreatedDate {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public string ErrText {get;set;}
    }
}
```

In the screenshot below, you can see I select Error_Text__c in the query, but it does not display in the results.  This was the results from it running on a record page.

[image]

But here, when I run it from execute anonymous, it displays the values correctly:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: your debug statements show different records. The first debug statement shows `OSE-189150, 062939, 063012, 189162`. The second shows `OSE-189132, 189133, 189134, 189135, 189136`. So your not comparing the same results/records. Now, whether the query results should be the same might point to an issue with how you're calling the method in Aura on the record page (possibly passing null recordId?) - which you haven't shown. Or your anonymous apex didn't pass the same recordId?

Comment: Oddly, the debug statements on line 8 also don't show Error_Text__c being returned at all, which makes me suspect that you are looking at the wrong version of your code as well. Make sure you're running in the correct org, as the correct user, and the correct version of your Apex code appears in Setup > Develop > Apex Classes.